# Where to put Datagridview be Place in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net

I am studying ASP.net webforms and i am confused where to placed Datagridview and other Controls
from webpage.aspx or in a Control.ascx .

//Which Validation and CRUD operations was performed

Which is the Best Practice.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ascx 
    - fragment
    - re-usable you can place it anytime in your webpages(aspx)
    - Need to attached to  aspx to make it works

---

aspx - the actual page it self which you call on your browser which your ascx are placed

---

have a look at this same post:

[Post 1](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1914-Difference-Between-usercontrol-custom-control.aspx)

[post 2](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/180941-What-ascx.aspx)

[Building User Controls](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020319.htm)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can put the thing in both but its depends on your requirement

aspx - is asp.net page so when you put control on it , it get utilize with in that page only i.e not resuable.

ascx - is user control , i.e usable control with in your application . once you design it you can use it in any page of by registering it on page.

so go for ascx when its resuable and going to use in no pages. go for aspx when its page specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your DataGridView (maybe including some search form, button) appear on every page. Then use ascx. Else aspx. Ascx is a page fragment, not page!